# EF6 Intercept SQL and log to DB OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, logging

I am trying to log my SQL that gets logged to a table but I'm receiving an OutOfMemoryException. I know why I get the exception but I don't know how to avoid it.

ApplicationDBContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser> {   
    public ApplicationDbContext() :
            base("IdentityDBContext", false) {
        DbInterception.Add(new InsertUpdateInterceptor());
    }
}
```

WebDataEntities:

```
   public WebDataEntities()
            : base("name=WebDataEntities")
        {
        }
```

Log class:

```
 public class InsertUpdateInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor {
        public virtual void NonQueryExecuting(
            DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext) {
            logCommand(command);
        }

        public virtual void ReaderExecuting(
            DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext) {
            // this will capture all SELECT queries if you care about them..
            // however it also captures INSERT statements as well 
            logCommand(command);
        }

        public virtual void ScalarExecuting(
         DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext) {
            logCommand(command);
        }


        private void logCommand(DbCommand dbCommand) {
            StringBuilder commandText = new StringBuilder();

            commandText.AppendLine("-- New statement generated: " + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
            commandText.AppendLine();

            // as the command has a bunch of parameters, we need to declare
            // those parameters here so the SQL will execute properly

            foreach (DbParameter param in dbCommand.Parameters) {
                var sqlParam = (SqlParameter)param;

                commandText.AppendLine(String.Format("DECLARE {0} {1} {2}",
                                                        sqlParam.ParameterName,
                                                        sqlParam.SqlDbType.ToString().ToLower(),
                                                        getSqlDataTypeSize(sqlParam)));

                var escapedValue = sqlParam.SqlValue.ToString().Replace("'", "''");
                commandText.AppendLine(String.Format("SET {0} = '{1}'", sqlParam.ParameterName, escapedValue));
                commandText.AppendLine();
            }

            commandText.AppendLine(dbCommand.CommandText);
            commandText.AppendLine("GO");
            commandText.AppendLine();
            commandText.AppendLine();

            using(var context = new WebDataEntities()) {
                context.tbl_FSV_AspNetIdentity_SQL_Log.Add(new tbl_FSV_AspNetIdentity_SQL_Log { Sql = commandText.ToString() });
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            //System.IO.File.AppendAllText("outputfile.sql", commandText.ToString());
        }

        private string getSqlDataTypeSize(SqlParameter param) {
            if (param.Size == 0) {
                return "";
            }

            if (param.Size == -1) {
                return "(MAX)";
            }

            return "(" + param.Size + ")";
        }


        // To implement the IDbCommandInterceptor interface you need to also implement these methods like so

        public void NonQueryExecuted(
            DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext) {
        }

        public void ReaderExecuted(
            DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext) {
        }

        public void ScalarExecuted(
            DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext) {
        }
    }
```

I am receiving the exception because when I'm trying to log the SQL, it gets stuck in a loop trying to log the sql which is supposed to log the sql to the DB. But I use two different contexts so why is it trying to log the SQL twice?

Comment: What is the class declaration for the WebDataEntities DbContext, it should hopefully not extend ApplicationDbContext.

Comment: It does not extend ApplicationDBContext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two important facts about EF's interception context:

- It is a global static singleton
- It's not dedicated to one context type.

Therefore, the line...

```
DbInterception.Add(new InsertUpdateInterceptor());
```

just adds a new `InsertUpdateInterceptor` instance to the interception context every time you create a new `ApplicationDbContext` *and* does so for every context type in your application.

That's why any commands in `WebDataEntities` cause infinite loops: they log themselves.

The solution is to use plain ADO.Net code (`SqlCommand` etc.) to log anything to the database inside command interceptors, or a different type of ORM (for example LINQ-to-SQL, which is still supported though running obsolete).

The line `DbInterception.Add(new InsertUpdateInterceptor())` should be called once at application startup. Executing it in `ApplicationDbContext` doesn't mean that it only applies to that instance. It's a static call, so it isn't aware of its environment.

Comment: I guess [DbContexts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev15.query?appId=Dev15IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbInterceptionContext.DbContexts%29%3Bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6%29%3Bk%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the interception context can be used for making a decision whether to log or not.

Comment: @Ivan I guess so too. OP may want to test whether it contains an instance of `ApplicationDbContext`.

Comment: Maybe it's even better to use an async logging mechanism to have the least amount of disturbance for the EF command. For example log4net. Another advantage of log4net is that it can be turned off in the application's config file.

Answer (score 0):

Gert's nailed it. I just noticed that in the second read-through. To add the interceptor to the single context:

```
public ApplicationDbContext() :
            base("IdentityDBContext", false) 
{
    this.AddInterceptor(new InsertUpdateInterceptor());
}
```